# IE8/9 jquery .load() vs other browsers act different

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys I have a file I need to upload it and I am doing it by using an iframe to upload the image as below as to not refresh the page.

```
<form id="uploadImg" target="iframe" action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
        <span>Choose File</span>
        <input id="imgToBeUploaded" type="file" class="upload" name="image"/>
    </div>
</form>

<iframe name="iframe" id="iframe" style="display:none" ></iframe>
```

My Javascript looks like this

```
$("iframe").load(function(){
    $('#image-uploaded').modal('show');
});

$('body').on('change','#imgToBeUploaded', function() {
    $("#uploadImg").submit();
});
```

Basically once the file is selected the form gets submitted and the bootstrap modal shows up.

In Chrome the expected behavior occurs, where once I submit the file the modal shows up. However in IE9 the modal shows up on page load AND form submission.

How can I prevent it from showing in page load?

Thank you

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Starting with 2.0, it no longer supported IE8. Is IE9 in Compatibility Mode?

Comment: @krillgar I have this running on IE9 to make it IE9 compatible <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> and Jquery version is 1.10.2

Comment: What would happen if you wrote $("iframe").on('load'... instead?